# m-BOX Mini wont record with Logic

Tags: audio-recording, logic-pro

I am using an mbox mini with a macbook, it has been working fine. But all of a sudden logic won't record. I get nothing from either channels, microphone or guitar, so it's not phantom power, it's not mic/line or di/line switches. I can hear the instrument or microphone fine when I listen to what's coming straight from the mbox. But for some reason it isn't making its way into logic. Logic is set to the mbox and play back plays fine. I have checked input assignments and it seems to be in order.

Any help would be much appreciated, I am stuck!

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me all the time with my mBox 2 in Logic. Generally unplugging the USB cable, waiting a minue and plugging it back in fixes it. I think it is caused by your computer going to sleep and then waking up (which I silly.)